# AWK (unexpected newline or end of string)

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to execute bash script but I'm got stuck.

**data**

```
$ cat test.txt 
cat,command,for
cp,command,for
ls,command,to
```

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash    

CUT_FILE=test.txt
TRN_GUID="1bcd1adf-2016-443b-9f00-2e4ce20726d7"
LCTN_ID="8002"
LCTN_NAME="TEST FILE"
LCTN_ADDR1="This is test"

cat $CUT_FILE | awk -F ','  '{ print  '$TRN_GUID','$LCTN_ID','$LCTN_NAME','$LCTN_ADDR1',$1,$2 }'
```

**output**

```
-bash-3.2# sh test4
awk: cmd. line:1: { print  1bcd1adf-2016-443b-9f00-2e4ce20726d7,8002,TEST
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                        ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

**desired output**

```
 1bcd1adf-2016-443b-9f00-2e4ce20726d7,8002,"TEST FILE","This is test",cat,command
```

Any ideas?

Comment: learn to use `set -vx` from your command line and then examine the lines preceded with `+`. These lines are where variables have expanded to their values. You should see (with a little thought), where things are breaking .Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Syntax Error

You are closing your script using the single quotes.

```
awk -F ','  '{ print  '$TRN_GUID','$LCTN_ID','$LCTN_NAME','$LCTN_ADDR1',$1,$2 }'
```

Can you see, using the syntax highlighting, that the script gets closed after `print  '`? You should use double quotation marks inside your script to prevent this, like so:

```
awk -F ','  '{ print "$TRN_GUID", "$LCTN_ID", "$LCTN_NAME", "$LCTN_ADDR1", $1, $2 }'
```

Do you notice the difference in syntax highlighting?

## Undesired output

You cannot access [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) variables inside [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), to accomplish this you should pass them as variables. To do that, we simply use the `-v` option of awk. To illustrate this point:

```
awk -v trn_guid="$TRN_GUID" -v lctn_id="LCTN_ID" -v lctn_name="$LCTN_NAME" -v lctn_addr1="$LCTN_ADDR1" -v arg1="$1" -v arg2="$2" -F ','  '{ print trn_guid, lctn_id, lctn_name, lctn_addr1, arg1, arg2 }'
```

The syntax is simply `-v variable="value"`. You can put anything in the value, including bash variables. The variable will be accessible in the awk script using the name you chose.

Comment: thnks shellFish@ i got below output after follow above syntax `$TRN_GUID $LCTN_ID $LCTN_NAME $LCTN_ADDR1 cat command
$TRN_GUID $LCTN_ID $LCTN_NAME $LCTN_ADDR1 cp command
$TRN_GUID $LCTN_ID $LCTN_NAME $LCTN_ADDR1 ls command`

Comment: You cannot access [tag:bash] variables inside [tag:awk], you'd have to pass them. I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: thanks@anubhava this method I already tried and it takes so much time when u hv high volume of files.Please let me know through awk.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need awk for this. Just use it like this in pure BASH:

```
CUT_FILE="test.txt"
TRN_GUID="1bcd1adf-2016-443b-9f00-2e4ce20726d7"
LCTN_ID="8002"
LCTN_NAME="TEST FILE"
LCTN_ADDR1="This is test"

while read -r line; do
   echo "$TRN_GUID,$LCTN_ID,$LCTN_NAME,$LCTN_ADDR1,${line%,*}"
done < "$CUT_FILE"
```

**Output:**

```
1bcd1adf-2016-443b-9f00-2e4ce20726d7,8002,TEST FILE,This is test,cat,command
1bcd1adf-2016-443b-9f00-2e4ce20726d7,8002,TEST FILE,This is test,cp,command
1bcd1adf-2016-443b-9f00-2e4ce20726d7,8002,TEST FILE,This is test,ls,command
```