# Awk in Ansible shell module provides unexpected newline or end of string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ansible

```
- shell: " su {{user}} -c 'ps -ef | awk \'{print $2}\''"
  register: result
```

received unexpected new line or end of string error after {print

I have to use su instead of the become plugins and also use the awk to filter the output

[AWK (unexpected newline or end of string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097457/awk-unexpected-newline-or-end-of-string)

Is there a way to escape " inside print for the below command. (\" didn't work)

```
"su {{user}} -c 'ps -ef | awk \'{print "$2"}\''"
```

Comment: Try `- shell: " su {{user}} -c 'ps -ef | awk \'{print \$2}\''"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-exhaustive list of escaping possibilities to reach your goal. The problem here is that yaml applies its own escape sequence before it reaches your shell. You can find more possibilities.

## Take 1:

```yaml
- shell: "su {{ user }} -c \"ps -ef | awk '{print \\$2}'\""
  register: result
```

## Take 2:

```yaml
- shell: su {{ user }} -c "ps -ef | awk '{print \$2}'"
  register: result
```

## Take 3:

```yaml
- shell: su {{ user }} -c 'ps -ef | awk "{print \$2}"'
  register: result
```

## Take 4 (Fixing solution from @Paolo):

```yaml
- shell: su {{ user }} -c 'ps -ef | awk '\''{print $2}'\'
  register: result
```

... to be continued eventually ...

Comment: So you've given 3 different options, which one is the solution? All of them?

Comment: All of them give the correct result. I just added one more based on your below answer.

Comment: Take 5: `- shell: | \n su {{ user }} -c "ps -ef | awk '{print \$2}'"`, with the YAML litteral, it makes it "easy" to work with shell commands: if it works on the host, it will work in the task, and YAML won't bother you with extra quotes or some more escaping :)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε your take 5 is exactly equivalent as my take 2. No need to put a block indicator when there is a single line ;)

Comment: True, but this is more like a "don't worry about YAML parsing oddities" way :)